# Woothemes flexslider Arrow not displaying

Tags: html, css, flexslider

I am using flexslider and but I just have a problem in terms of its navigation arrow. It's not displaying the right way even if I already put the font source to the right folder.

I used the flex slider in my wordpress theme and here is a screenshot of the arrow.

[image]

Here is the `css` file [jsfiddle.net/fdeZd/](http://jsfiddle.net/fdeZd/)

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply putting the font folder of flex slider inside my css folder where my flex slider.css can be found. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The arrows were displayed as in your screenshot no matter where I placed the font files.
I even tried absolute links á la "src:url('d:/myProject/fonts/flexslider-icon.eot');" and it still didn't work. I think it has something to do

with the font itself.

But good news: I used the following workaround:

I'm using font Arial and the two symbols "<" and ">".

You have to adjust the file flexslider.css the following way:

This line:

```
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
    font-family:"flexslider-icon";
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height:1;
    display: inline-block;
    content:'\f001';
}
```

has to be replaced by the following one:

```
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height:1;
    display: inline-block;
    content:'<';
}
```

And this line:

```
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
    content:'\f002';
}
```

has to be replaced by the following one:

```
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
    content:'>';
}
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You should check existing files:

- flexslider-icon.eot
- flexslider-icon.svg
- flexslider-icon.ttf
- flexslider-icon.woff

  in including directory (in **flexslider.css** line: 15)